# Can Flot plot a vector field?

Tags: flot

I have some JS that explores some properties of a planar model and the mechanism that causes a phase transition in a lattice of spins. One indicator of a phase transition is the way the spins are oriented in the lattice, and for that I would like to plot a [vector field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_field). Can Flot do that?

Comment: Do you have to use flot? - pretty nice one here in d3.js - http://bl.ocks.org/adrianturcato/cf665b7cca9f6057691a

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do this with one small change to the flot library. In the `drawSeriesPoints(series)` function (line 1986 in version 0.7) change the line

```
symbol(ctx, x, y, radius, shadow);
```

to this

```
symbol(ctx, x, y, radius, shadow, series, Math.floor(i / ps));
```

This is done so that you can access the datapoint when drawing it.

Format your data points in the form `[x coordinate, y coordinate, vector angle, vector length]` and use a custom symbol function like this:

```
function vector(ctx, x, y, radius, shadow, series, index) {

  var vectorAngle = series.data[index][2]; // in radians
  var vectorLength = series.data[index][3]; // in pixels

  var bottom = [Math.round(x + vectorLength * Math.sin(vectorAngle)), Math.round(y - vectorLength * Math.cos(vectorAngle))];
  var top = [Math.round(x - vectorLength * Math.sin(vectorAngle)), Math.round(y + vectorLength * Math.cos(vectorAngle))];
  var left = [top[0] - (top[0] - bottom[0]) / 4 + (top[1] - bottom[1]) / 4, top[1] - (top[1] - bottom[1]) / 4 - (top[0] - bottom[0]) / 4];
  var right = [top[0] - (top[0] - bottom[0]) / 4 - (top[1] - bottom[1]) / 4, top[1] - (top[1] - bottom[1]) / 4 + (top[0] - bottom[0]) / 4];

  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(top[0], top[1]);
  ctx.lineTo(left[0], left[1]);
  ctx.lineTo(right[0], right[1]);
  ctx.lineTo(top[0], top[1]);
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.fillStyle = series.color;
  ctx.fill();

  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(top[0], top[1])
  ctx.lineTo(bottom[0], bottom[1]);
  ctx.stroke();

  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(x, y);
}
```

[Complete example as fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/pr88fg4u/)